# JPA, complex object graphs and Serialisation

Tags: java, database, jpa, jdo

I have a "Project" entity/class that includes a number of "complex" fields, eg referenced as interfaces with many various possible implementations. To give an example: an interface Property, with T virtually of any type (as many types as I have implemented).

I use JPA. For those fields I have had no choice but to actually serialize them to store them. Although I have no need to use those objects in my queries, this is obviously leading to some issues, eg maintenance/updates to start with.

I have two questions:

1) is there a "trick" I could consider to keep my database up to date in case I have a "breaking" change in my serialised class (most of the time serialisation changes are handled well)?

2) will moving to JDO help at all? I very little experience with JDO but my understanding is that with JDO, having serialised objects in the tables will never happen (how are changes handled though?).
In support to 2) I must also add that the object graphs I have can be quite complex, possibly involving 10s of tables just to retrieve a full "Project" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

JDO obviously supports persistence of interface fields (but then DataNucleus JPA also allows their persistence, but as vendor extension). Having some interface field being one of any possible type presents problems to **RDBMS** rather than to JDO as such. The underlying datastore is more your problem (in not being able to adequately mirror your model), and one of the many many other datastores could help you with that. For example DataNucleus JDO/JPA supports GAE/Datastore, Neo4j, MongoDB, HBase, ODF, Excel, etc and simply persists the "id" of the related object in a "column" (or equivalent) in the owning object representation ... so such breaking changes would be much much less than what you have now